# Wordpress: PHP Function inside a Shortcode. How?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Here's what I'd like to do. This function which grabs the content of a custom Wordpress post field:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'society_twitter', true);
```

Needs to run in place of the string 'yourTwitterUsername' below,

```
[twitter-widget username="yourTwitterUsername"]
```

Looking something like:

```
[twitter-widget username="get_post_meta($post->ID, 'society_twitter', true);"]
```

Is this possible? If so, what is the syntax? A little more detail: I'm trying to modify a Twitter widget to display the username listed in a custom post field in my database rather than just one string value. I've tried editing the plugin php itself but this seems like an easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string concatenation?

```
$string = '[twitter-widget username="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'society_twitter', true) . '"]';
```

**Edit:** Updated based on the comments:

```
$string = '[twitter-widget username="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'society_twitter', true) . '"]';
echo do_shortcode( $string);
```

Comment: It depends on how you're generating `[twitter-widget username="yourTwitterUsername"]`.

Comment: `echo do_shortcode('[twitter-widget username="yourTwitterUsername"]');`

Comment: So it'd look like `echo do_shortcode($string = '[twitter-widget username="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'society_twitter', true) . '"]');` ?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer to put it to two lines, but yes, except without the `$string = ` in your code.

Comment: Brilliant, works like a charm. Will mark as answered ASAP. Thanks!